# new row violates row-level security policy for table "tasks"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, supabase, supabase-database, bluebase

I am new to supabase and am trying to integrate my Todo App made with BlueBase, a Framework based on react and react native. And, I am facing such a problem.

**CreateTaskScreen.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';

import CreateTaskForm from '../../components/CreateTaskForm';

export const CreateTaskScreen = () => {
    return (
        <CreateTaskForm />
    );
};

CreateTaskScreen.displayName = 'CreateTaskScreen';
```

**index.ts**

```
export * from './CreateTaskScreen';

import { CreateTaskScreen } from './CreateTaskScreen';
export default CreateTaskScreen;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the API URL and API Key carefully. It will resolve your

> new row violates row-level security policy for table "tasks"

error. And also follow the blue base documentation to create a table carefully. Enter Table Name, Type, and Default Value carefully.
Also, the default value of id is `uuid_generate_v4()`. You can see it in the suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Adding a policy** seems like the best way, with this you don't need to **disable the RLS policy** and **don't need to use a secret key** which is very unsafe for your data.

To do this,

1. Go to **"Authentication"** > **"Policies"** > Select the **"New
   Policy"** table
   [image]
2. Then add from the template for policy insert data.
   [image]
3. Follow the next steps
   [image]
4. Review your policy
5. Save New Policy